# Nuget package installation does not copy files in lib folder

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I have created a nuget package using NuGet Package Explorer containing only one DLL file. When I install it using Package Manager Console, it says installation was successful, but no file is copied into the `bin` folder after rebuilding the project. The DLL file is compiled resources for localizing `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`.
The package is available from this link:
[Download the package file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vHPiDHRIM3JpHiR4IWQ5XxL44lAkLKyL)
What is wrong with my package and what should I do?

Comment: I think the problem is that the name of the lib folder does not match the satellite NuGet package name. You have `AspNet.Identity.Core.fa.nupkg` as the NuGet package filename but you are using `lib/net45/fa-lR`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-localized-packages#summary-of-required-conventions

Comment: @MattWard thanks alot. That's it. I have read the link and now it works.

Comment: @MattWard Whould you please post an answer to mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the name of the lib folder does not match the satellite NuGet package filename.

You have AspNet.Identity.Core.fa.nupkg as the NuGet package filename but you are using a lib/net45/fa-lR folder.

Information taken from the [Creating localized NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-localized-packages#summary-of-required-conventions) page is shown below:

## Summary of required conventions

- Primary package must be named {identifier}.{version}.nupkg
- A satellite package must be named {identifier}.{language}.{version}.nupkg
- A satellite package's .nuspec must specify its language to match the filename.
- A satellite package must declare a dependency on an exact version of the primary using the [] notation in its .nuspec file. Ranges are not supported.
- A satellite package must place files in the lib[{framework}]{language} folder that exactly matches {language} in the filename.